# Do two points on the surface of a sphere uniquely describe a great cirlce?

Tags: spherical-geometry

I had a debate with a buddy about this. He said you could get a chord by drawing the triangle formed by the two points and the center of the sphere and that chord corresponds to a single great circle arc. I can get to the chord but then projecting that chord on to a path on the surface of the sphere seems non obvious.

So is it true that two points not colinear with the spheres center on the surface of a sphere have a unique great circle connecting them and if so how does one prove it?

Comment: If the two points are neither identical nor antipodal, then the triangle with the two points and  the centre of the sphere is not degenerate, and so it lies on a unique plane.  This plane's intersection with the sphere then defines a unique circle, which is a great circle as the plane contains the centre of the sphere. Any great circle through the two points would have lie on a plane containing the two points and the centre of the sphere and so the triangle, so would be the same plane and same great circle.

Comment: In particular, note that the claim fails when the two points are antipodal (that is, are directly opposite each other through the center of the sphere). All great circles passing through a point on the sphere will also pass through its antipodal point, so a pair of antipodal points do not determine a unique great circle. Henry's construction fails in this case, as the two antipodal points and the center of the sphere are collinear, so they do not determine a unique plane, unlike any three non-collinear points.